# Фраза, яка містить у собі усі літери української абетки

Tags: абетка, mnemonic

Потрібен якийсь еквівалент англійської фрази *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*, яка містить у собі **усі** літери української абетки.

Фраза повинна мати якийсь сенс, а не бути набором випадкових і абсолютно нічим не пов'язаних слів.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Фраза, яку ви шукаєте назвається [Панграма](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0)

У Вікіпедії за посиланням є чимало варантів панграм, наприклад

> Єхидна, ґава, їжак ще й шиплячі плазуни бігцем форсують Янцзи

Однак жодна з них не стала таким стандартом як "The quick brown fox..."

Comment: Ідеально. Дякую!

Answer (score 1):

Знайшла: "Жебракують філософи при ґанку церкви в Гадячі, ще й шатро їхнє п'яне знаємо".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти. Відповідь на конкретно це запитання складно якось розширити чи на щоь послатися, тому спільнота її скоріш за все прийме. Втім, на майбутнє пам'ятайте, що на цьому сайті заохочуються відповіді з посиланням на джерела. Ще раз вітаю і сподіваюсь на плідну співпрацю.

Comment: Так, дякую за ще одну, але мені вже пояснили, що це зветься панграмою, і звідти шукати подібні фрази було дуже легко.